# Send client other players score? Socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

I have a situation where I am not sure how to send the other client their competitors current score.

For example:

When player 1 clicks I want it to then tell player two the score of player one on the client side.

```
    userOne = userIDs[0];
    userTwo = userIDs[1];

    socket.on("player one", function(data) {
        console.log(data.pScore + "THIS IS WORKING");
        score = data.pScore;
        console.log("THIS IS PLAYER TWO" + data.pNameTwo);
        if (isInArray(data.pNameTwo,allUsers)) {
            console.log(users[socket.id].username);
        }
        socket.emit("player ones score", {p1Score: score});
    });

    socket.on("player two", function(data) {
        console.log(data.pScore + "THIS IS WORKING");
        score = data.pScore;
        socket.emit("player twos score", {p2Score: score});
    });
```

I was going to send off the score by emitting only to a specific user ID. But im not sure the best way to do so.

Comment: make a game objects both users can see that has the other players linked.

Comment: How would one do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do so is to have an object containing all connections, which is updated every time a user connects/disconnects. I see you already have a userIDs list of their IDs, so, if your object is called userConnections, your code should be...

```
userOne = userIDs[0];
userTwo = userIDs[1];

socket.on("player one", function(data) {
    console.log(data.pScore + "THIS IS WORKING");
    score = data.pScore;
    console.log("THIS IS PLAYER TWO" + data.pNameTwo);
    if (isInArray(data.pNameTwo,allUsers)) {
        console.log(users[socket.id].username);
    }
    userConnections[userTwo].emit("player ones score", {p1Score: score});
});

socket.on("player two", function(data) {
    console.log(data.pScore + "THIS IS WORKING");
    score = data.pScore;
    userConnections[userOne].emit("player twos score", {p2Score: score});
});
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, I'll show how to initialize and manage userConnections too. It goes like this (I'm only guessing how some variables in your code are called, so I may get some names wrong).

```
var userConnections = {}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    userConnections[socket.id] = socket;

    //socket.on('player one', function(data) { ... } );
    //socket.on('player two', function(data) { ... } );

    socket.on('disconnect') {
        delete userConnections[socket.id];
    }
}
```

Comment: what is userConnections calling?

Comment: Because I tried what you have there but says cannot read property emit of undefined

Comment: I was being silly when I could of just run a global emit io.sockets.emit and gotten the values there. But thanks for enlightening me as that led me on the right path.

Comment: @factor_za Oh, I see. I'm glad you found the way to do this. I'm such a slowpoke - I've expanded my answer. Anyway I'm not sure how my answer helped (since it wasn't very close to that), but you're welcome.

Comment: Haha it made me think and look for a solution. This is my first socket.io project. so at the moment its very ugly! Thanks again.